# Check string for word, then add text to end of word

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of long strings (from JSON) that I want to check when i load them in.

They should be checked for the word "youtube.com/v/" which is within a src tag within an embed.

The youtube video can be anywhere within the string and there can be multiple ones.

After "youtube.com/v/" there is the name of the video like "CtgYY7dhTyE".

After "CtgYY7dhTyE" it should add "?theme=light&color=white" or "?theme=dark&color=white" depending on another jQuery variable. Its because i can switch themes at runtime of the site. A dark and a light theme. I want the youtube video to change according to that.

Hope someone can figure this one out.

I have no problems in loading them in and displaying them. Everything works fine except for the youtube embed not changing theme when it gets loaded in.

Comment: And does the video name always end with an `E`, or is it always the same length, or is there always some other character where the name ends etc. We'll need to know where the name ends to insert something after it ?

Comment: It has 11 characters after /v/ .. its after those it should be inserted, for all the "youtube.com/v/" in the string